# How do I disable the status buttons for Cisco Jabber in the taskbar preview?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, cisco-jabber

Hovering over the taskbar icon for an active program in Windows 7 typically displays a list of open windows to select from. Cisco Jabber adds an extra taskbar feature for changing your current user status with three colored buttons (Available, Away, Do Not Disturb).

[image: Jabber taskbar preview]

I often find myself accidentally changing my status when I'm trying to switch windows. I'd like to remove or disable these buttons entirely if possible.

**How can I disable the buttons for changing my current status in Cisco Jabber's taskbar preview?**

Comment: You would have to disable Taskbar Previews entirely. What is displayed within the Taskbar Preview for an application, is up to the programmer, verify the application doesn't have an option to change this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried [disabling taskbar previews](https://www.guidingtech.com/12253/turn-off-windows-7-taskbar-thumbnail-previews/), but Jabber's status icons still appear.